# How to configure XAMPP to use PHP debugger

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to configure XAMPP to debug. I've got the Xdebug dll from the site with my PHP version and put it in my `ext` fold, but when I change the php.ini with the next code and restart Apache, the localhost link stops working.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.1.0-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Someone who can help me here and ho to configure VSCode.

Comment: *"php_xdebug-3.1.0*" -- Start here first: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide . Then check https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: FWIW, there are some crash bugs with Apache on Windows that we're trying to sort out at the moment... But @LazyOne is not wrong, read the upgrade guide too. Sadly, the learnxdebug.com site is still mostly for Xdebug 2, but I've lots of material at https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLg9Kjjye-m1g_eXpdaifUqLqALLqZqKd4

Comment: @JoãoPereira **1)** Yeah, try Xdebug **3.0.4** instead of 3.1.0. There were a few complaints that TS version of Xdebug 3.1 crashes on Windows (Apache from XAMPP uses TS version of PHP). **2)** And go through the Upgrade Guide -- your config tells that you are using params from Xdebug v2 but they do nothing in Xdebug v3.